# Guy get isekaied and is the only male in a monster-girl world

Tags: story-identification, manga, anime, isekai

Human guy gets isekaied into a world of only females and monster girls where his only ability is to make females want him.

He gets attacked my slime girls (a lot) and has a female companion who's dense but really strong.

He meets a Coe(?) at an inn and meets a priest nun who helps him find a sword that talks to him.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You've tagged this both "manga" and "anime;" is it a manga or an anime?  Also, where and when did you read/watch this?

Answer (score 1):

Could this be *[Parallel Paradise](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_Paradise)*?

> Youta Tada is an ordinary high school student who holds deep feelings for his childhood friend. One day during class, he is suddenly attacked and seemingly killed by a mysterious scarecrow-like being. Youta then wakes up and finds himself in an alternate world with castles, dragons and two colored moons in a purple sky. Here he meets paladin girl Lumi and a three-legged bird named Genius and quickly learns that he got into a women-only world where he is the first man that appeared in centuries. Thanks to that, women in this world have absolutely no resistance towards him and his single touch makes Lumi incredibly aroused. Genius then orders him to mate with her and all other girls in this fantastical world
>
> [image]

You may wish to note that this title has attracted some controversy over [claims that it promotes child pornography](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2020-07-21/books-kinokuniya-sydney-removes-7-manga-after-lawmaker-child-pornography-complaint/.162070).

Comment: I guess this proves that anime (er, manga in this case) was a mistake.